# Python slackclient "Operation timed out" error

Tags: python, websocket, slack-api

I am trying to build a slack-bot in python(3.x),  for this I am using [slackClient](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient).

After running for an unkown number of hours "TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Operation timed out" exception was thrown.

**Logs :**

```
command, channel, user = parse_bot_commands(slack_client.rtm_read())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/slackclient/client.py", line 235, in rtm_read
    json_data = self.server.websocket_safe_read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/slackclient/server.py", line 278, in websocket_safe_read
    data += "{0}\n".format(self.websocket.recv())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 302, in recv
    opcode, data = self.recv_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 319, in recv_data
    opcode, frame = self.recv_data_frame(control_frame)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 332, in recv_data_frame
    frame = self.recv_frame()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 366, in recv_frame
    return self.frame_buffer.recv_frame()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/websocket/_abnf.py", line 361, in recv_frame
    self.recv_header()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/websocket/_abnf.py", line 309, in recv_header
    header = self.recv_strict(2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/websocket/_abnf.py", line 396, in recv_strict
    bytes_ = self.recv(min(16384, shortage))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 441, in _recv
    return recv(self.sock, bufsize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/websocket/_socket.py", line 81, in recv
    bytes_ = sock.recv(bufsize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 922, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 799, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 585, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Operation timed out
```

**code :**

[slack-bot-github](https://github.com/cmaliwal/slack-bot)

Comment: Please don't just link your git repo, but include the part of the code that is relevant to your problem in your question. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about what constitutes a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: Things is that , issue is not in code . Issue in Slack client library . 
That's why I didn't paste the code .

Comment: In that case I think it would be better to open an issue against python-slackclient
on github. Don't think the Stack Overflow community will be able to help you.

Comment: I already did it .
But looks like peoples solve the issue but didn't share on github that's why I thought to ask the question on stackoverflow .